# How do i set properties in DatabaseConfig in spring boot

Tags: database, hibernate, spring-boot

Before i had my configs in application.properties. But now it dosen't seem to do anything, so i guess i need to set them in conf class.

All the examples and tutorials seem to just casualy setProperties to LocalContaierEntityManagerFactoryBean but there is no such option here or i have no idea how...

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableTransactionManagement
 @EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
    basePackages = "com.xxxx.xxxxx.database.local.repository"
 )
public class LocalDatabaseConfig {

@Bean(name = "localDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource localDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();

}
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
        entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("localDataSource") DataSource localDataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(localDataSource)
            .packages("com.xxxx.xxxxx.database.local.model")
            .persistenceUnit("local")
            .build();
}
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory")EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}

Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    properties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

    return properties;
}

}
```

I have method additionalProperties, but cant figure how to setProperties on any of the objects here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean will override the auto-create from application.properties.

You can set it by inserting it in configuration.

```
    @Primary
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
        entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("localDataSource") DataSource localDataSource) {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    return builder.dataSource(localDataSource)
            .packages("com.evli.kickback.database.local.model")
            .persistenceUnit("local")
            .properties(properties)
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner approach is to put all of these configurations in application.properties file.
Create a file named **application.properties** in `/src/main/resources`. 
Spring automatically detects it as a configuration file and loads all of the needed properties. 
eg.-

### Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/notes_app?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root


## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

### For more than one data source, use the following configuration-

```
#first db
spring.datasource.url = [url]
spring.datasource.username = [username]
spring.datasource.password = [password]
spring.datasource.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

#second db ...
spring.secondDatasource.url = [url]
spring.secondDatasource.username = [username]
spring.secondDatasource.password = [password]
spring.secondDatasource.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver


@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.firstDatasource")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.secondDatasource")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

For more than one datasource, you can use @ConfigurationProperties annotation with prefix string, identifying your datasource.

Comment: My configurations dont seem to work from application properties, since i have two datasources. can i somehow use the prefix to only give this property to one source?

Comment: Just updated my answer for more than one data source configuration.

Comment: how about if i only want to use spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update on second data source?